# extension of derivation of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, lie-algebras

I am studying extension of derivations, but I am confused of some notations and maybe symbols! For some more details, I recall a theorem.
We have the following theorem :

> Theorem: Let $A$ be an algebra separable over its center $C$ and $M$ be an $A \otimes A^{op}$-module. Then any derivation $d: C \to M^{A}$  extends to $\bar{d}: A \to M$.

My questions are as follows:

- What does it mean: Algebra over its center? Is it possible to consider Algebra over any field?
- What is  $A \otimes A^{op}$-module? I need more details on  $ A^{op}$?
- Can we consider $d$ as a derivation from  subalgebra of $A$ instead of $C$?
- What does this symbol $M^{A}$ stand for?

Comment: Where did you get this theorem from? Does that source not even explain its notation?

Comment: It belongs to a paper from MICHAEL BARR AND MAX-ALBERT KNUS
.  without enough details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For any field $k$, a $k$-algebra (associative with unit) is a ring $A$ together with a ring homomorphism $k\ \longrightarrow\ C$, where $C$ is the center of $A$. If the center $C$ is a field, then $A$ is also a $C$-algebra because the inclusion $C\ \longrightarrow\ A$ is a ring homomorphism.
- The structure of $A$ tells you everything about $A^{\text{op}}$; they are isomorphic as rings.
- Yes, because $C$ *is* a subalgebra of $A$.
- Thanks to Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: The symbol $M^A$ denotes the subspace of $M$ of central elements, i.e. elements $m\in M$ for which $am=ma$ holds for all $a\in A$.

Comment: $M^A$ does **not** denote that. It denotes the subpace of M of central elements, that is, elements m of M such that am=ma for all a in A.

Comment: A fixed algebra A cannot be viewed as an algebra over "any field".

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thanks for your first comment, I was not aware of this (this is not my field, no pun intended). For your second comment; I'll rephrase that sentence not to be so ambiguous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I have one more question about considering non-associative algebras? I thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: I know nothing of them, except that they make me cry.

Comment: I mean, let consider $A$ as a Lie algebra, then can we use these theorem to extend a derivation of Lie algebra?